# Exception thrown with Entity Framework adding new row to the DB

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, entity-framework

I've been trying for a while to debug this and express what I want to do in different ways, but am having no luck.  I don't know a whole lot about the entity framework, and I inherited this code from another developer who's no longer around so I don't know a whole lot about the model.  Perhaps someone can at least get me pointed in the right direction.  Here's my code:

```
//Append note to project notes too
task.TPM_PROJECTVERSIONReference.Load();
TPM_PROJECTVERSIONNOTES newNote = new TPM_PROJECTVERSIONNOTES();
newNote.TS = System.DateTime.Now;
newNote.TPM_USER = SessionHandler.LoginUser;
newNote.NOTES = task.NOTES;
newNote.PROJECTID = this.ProjectId;
newNote.VERSIONID = this.VersionId;
task.TPM_PROJECTVERSION.TPM_PROJECTVERSIONNOTES.Add(newNote); //<-- Exception
```

I have "task", which points to a project version it belongs to.  These projects have a bunch of notes.  I want to add a new note to the task's project.  However, I get an exception on the last line:

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
>   Message=The relationship between the two objects cannot be
>   defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.
>   Source=System.Data.Entity

This seems like it should be a pretty simple thing.  Is this not the right way to do this?  Thanks!

**Edit:**

Ok I've removed ALL other code from the function and created a brand new context.  Here's the entire function now from start to finish:

```
//Append note to project notes too
using (TPMEntities context = new TPMEntities(General.EntityName()))
{
   TPM_PROJECTVERSIONNOTES newNote = context.TPM_PROJECTVERSIONNOTES.CreateObject();
   newNote.TS = System.DateTime.Now;
   newNote.TPM_USER = SessionHandler.LoginUser;
   newNote.NOTES = this.txtTaskNotes.Text;
   TPM_PROJECTVERSION version = (from pv in context.TPM_PROJECTVERSION
                                 where pv.PROJECTID == this.ProjectId && pv.VERSIONID == this.VersionId
                                 select pv).First();

   version.TPM_PROJECTVERSIONNOTES.Add(newNote);
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Still, I get the same exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  Message=The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.
  Source=System.Data.Entity
```

I simply can't understand how there can be two contexts?  I'm using "context" every single place in the code.  How can the Entity Framework make it so difficult to simply add a single row into my database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in

```
newNote.TPM_USER = SessionHandler.LoginUser;
```

`LoginUser` is created using another context. You are attaching that to `context`. There are couple of ways to solve this.

Detach the `LoginUser` from the context it was created.

```
sessionContext.Detach(SessionHandler.LoginUser);
```

Then inside your method

```
using (TPMEntities context = new TPMEntities(General.EntityName()))
{
   context.Attach(SessionHandler.LoginUser);

   TPM_PROJECTVERSIONNOTES newNote = context.TPM_PROJECTVERSIONNOTES.CreateObject();
   newNote.TS = System.DateTime.Now;
   newNote.TPM_USER = SessionHandler.LoginUser;
   newNote.NOTES = this.txtTaskNotes.Text;
   TPM_PROJECTVERSION version = (from pv in context.TPM_PROJECTVERSION
                                 where pv.PROJECTID == this.ProjectId && pv.VERSIONID == this.VersionId
                                 select pv).First();

   version.TPM_PROJECTVERSIONNOTES.Add(newNote);
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Or if you have mapped the scalar foreign key property `newNote.TPM_USER_ID`

```
using (TPMEntities context = new TPMEntities(General.EntityName()))
{
   TPM_PROJECTVERSIONNOTES newNote = context.TPM_PROJECTVERSIONNOTES.CreateObject();
   newNote.TS = System.DateTime.Now;
   newNote.TPM_USER_ID = SessionHandler.LoginUser.ID;
   newNote.NOTES = this.txtTaskNotes.Text;
   TPM_PROJECTVERSION version = (from pv in context.TPM_PROJECTVERSION
                                 where pv.PROJECTID == this.ProjectId && pv.VERSIONID == this.VersionId
                                 select pv).First();

   version.TPM_PROJECTVERSIONNOTES.Add(newNote);
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your Web.Config Connection String to include MultipleActiveResultSets=True.

Comment: So what's your reasoning?  Is this because I'm doing a bunch of editing with the "task" and I can't add new relations to it at the same time?

Comment: Ah...not using MS SQL. I had a similar problem and making the change fixed it. Not sure exactly how EF handles DB transactions, but I do know that it has to do handle multiple result sets to maintain it's OO approach. I usually load the DB context as a module level variable and use it throughout the class so I don't get issues with multiple context objects. (Note: sometimes you need multiple contexts).

Comment: Yea this code is happening within a using() block which creates the context.  There /should/ only be one context..

Comment: Is 'task' defined inside, outside or as a parameter of the using() block?

Comment: Not really.  Task is declared within the using block, but we load it with a function: task = TaskManager.GetTaskIfExists(context, this.TaskId); -- However, that function uses the same context and dose a LINQ query to load the TPM_TASK object from the database.  Since the context was passed in, that should be fine right?

Comment: Why not just do 'TaskManager _db = new TaskManager();' and just use _db instead of task? Then everything in the block is for sure using the same context. At least you could eliminate that as a problem.

Comment: TaskManager is an abstract utility class.  I don't understand how creating a row in the database can possibly be this complicated with the Entity framework.  It's one line of SQL code.

Comment: Lol! I'm using EF on a project that is SQL Server-based and the code is MVC 3-based. It works beautifully if you are within that box! I have yet to pick it apart.

Answer (score 0):

Welp after nearly 4 hours of trying to make this work, the only solution I could actually get working is this one.  Apparently inserting new data into the database is an advanced feature of the Entity Framework that require in-depth knowledge of its inner workings.

```
context.ExecuteStoreQuery<object>("INSERT INTO TPM_PROJECTVERSIONNOTES (NOTES, PROJECTID, VERSIONID, USERID, TS) VALUES (:notes, :projId, :versionId, :userId, :timestamp)",
   new OracleParameter("notes", this.txtTaskNotes.Text),
   new OracleParameter("projId", this.ProjectId),
   new OracleParameter("versionId", this.VersionId),
   new OracleParameter("userId", SessionHandler.LoginUser.USERID),
   new OracleParameter("timestamp", DateTime.Now));
```

Oh well, at least it's fast.